# Есть ли способ избежать ухудшения качества обрабатываемого гиф-изображения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

вставляю некоторую информацию на каждый кадр гифки, но на выходе получаю плохое качество... Можно ли это как-то предотвратить?

Параметры сохранения:

```
fps = 25
ims[0].save(".gif", save_all=True, append_images=ims[1:], duration=1000/fps, quality=100)
```

[Оригинал](https://i.giphy.com/media/BEUy0HyVy80Gk/giphy.webp)
[Выходное изображение](https://i.imgur.com/Oq64d86.gif)

Comment: Возможно дело в разрешении

Comment: Может поможет < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248089/images-lose-quality-after-saving-as-gif>

Answer (score 2):

Понял в чём проблема, я конвертировал из `webp` в `gif`, теперь же я оставляю формат таким же и на выходе не теряю качество.

Comment: А, ну да, у гифки какое-то очень ограниченное число цветов, если я правильно помню